# Does "which wouldn’t have been at all unusual except it was during a rainstorm" mean "it would generally be 'usual' but not during a rainstorm"?

Tags: meaning

Full text:

> . . . the hours I’d spent hauling scrap.
>   When Dad saw me with one of those books, he’d try to get me away from
>   them. Perhaps he was remembering Tyler. Perhaps he thought if he could
>   just distract me for a few years, the danger would pass. So he made up jobs
>   for me to do, whether they needed doing or not. One afternoon, after he’d
>   caught me looking at the math book, he and I spent an hour hauling
>   buckets of water across the field to his fruit trees, **which wouldn’t have
>   been at all unusual except it was during a rainstorm.**
>
> Tara Westover: *Educated*

Comment: What part or which words do you not understand? The phrase itself seems pretty clear, but maybe there are words you don't understand?

Comment: Can you please identify the parts you understand and the parts where you're having an issue? This may be closed as off-topic because we cannot identify the problem you are having with the sentence fragment.

Comment: @oerkelens I don't understand what is the relationship between the phrase and the rest. However, the phrase itself doesn't seem to be very clear.(at least for me)

Comment: @psosuna Could you tell me to which words refer "which" and "it"? ("which" wouldn’t have been at all unusual except "it" was during a rainstorm)

Comment: Do you understand "buckets of water" and for what purpose they were for?

Comment: @Mari-Lou yes. For watering the trees?

Comment: Great! So is it normal to carry buckets of water (presumably) to pour water onto the fruit trees's soil while there is a rainstorm?

Comment: @ Mari-Lou No. It is n't normal. But I can 't get the point!  Could you rewrite the phrase?

Comment: @ Mari-Lou  Does it mean "it would be "usual" except it was during a rainstorm?

Comment: @ Mari-Lou  I think I get the point. It means  it would be usual but not during a rainstorm. Is it correct?

Comment: @Peace Could you please reword your question to address the issues you were having with the phrase? That way, we can give a proper answer to your question.

Comment: @psosuna  My prblem was solved. I got the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

In response to the comment on the original question:

'Which' and 'it' both refer to the phrase directly before;

> *he and I spent an hour hauling buckets of water across the field to his fruit trees*

I am really not sure how to better explain this...